# what happens to the transactions inside an uncle block And what if a contract creation end up in an uncle block

Tags: transactions, mining, txpool, uncle-blocks

Can anyone  suggest  what happens to the transactions inside an uncle block ?
And what if a contract creation end up in an uncle block.

The whitepaper(ethereum) does not give any information whether the tx in uncle blocks go to the mempool or not. But I am sure that the uncle block transactions do not contribute to the state tree change. Still unsure whether they are automatically reverted and taken to the mempool as pending ones

And also, is the uncle reward being shared if there are children to an uncle block ?

Comment: Hi @RichardHorrocks thanks but the subject of query has same however my question is different from it as he asked  'What happens to the transactions when a miner's block is declared invalid?'

Comment: When the other question mentions a block being "invalid" I think it just means "when it becomes an uncle". So the answer is the same: the transactions go back into the mempool and don't contribute any changes to the world state. (Unless the same transactions are also included in the accepted block as well.)

Comment: thanks for reply However I have one confusion that, is the uncle reward being shared if there are children to an uncle block ?

Comment: Hi @RichardHorrocks I am Still unsure whether they are automatically reverted and taken to the mempool as pending ones.

Comment: For your first question, a maximum of 2 uncles can be included per accepted block. The miner who successfully mines the block and includes those uncles gets a small reward. The unsuccessful miners who found each of the uncles also get a reward to compensate them for their unsuccessful work. Note that the same miner could have found both uncles, rather than there being two miners to share the uncle reward.

Comment: For your second question, yes, they are automatically reverted and put back in the mempool. The block/small chain in which those transactions existed no longer exists.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHorrocks for reply now its clear thanks for your effort :-)

Comment: No problem, happy to help :-)